# Next.js ISR. fetch request not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js, interrupt

## I need to implement an ISR in the project, but when I add the getStaticProps function and follow the documentation example, the data is not displayed. `

```
 import style from "./style.module.css";
     interface Product {
      id: number;
      title: string;
      price: number;
    }
    interface ProductsProps {
      data: Product[];
    }
    export default function products({ data }: ProductsProps) {
       return (
        <>
          <div className={style["products-wrapper"]}>
            {data?.map((el: Product) => (
              <div className={style.flex} key={el.id}>
                <div className={style.img}></div>
                <h1>{el.title}</h1>
                <p>{el.price}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    export async function getStaticProps() {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/products");
      const data = await response.json();
      return {
        props: {
          data,
        },
        revalidate: 60, 
      };                          
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.